# Changing the QWidget parent while in a mousePressEvent() doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I'm changing the parent widget of a `QWidget` that I click for the purposes of dragging that widget around the area of the parent. I need to change the parent while I'm in the `mousePressEvent()` callback because the frame of the previous parent is very limited.

This produces the unintended result of seemingly losing the mouse event and having to click again before I can start responding to `mouseMoveEvent()`.

All I have in the event when this happens is the following.

```
cardWidget->setParent(feltWidget);
cardWidget->show();
```

If I remove the `setParent()` call it works as intended. How do make it so that I'm still able to change the parent, but it doesn't appear as if the current object my mouse cursor is destroyed and a new gets created.

Comment: It seems like you should just use drag and drop instead of the parent switch hack.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem involving changing a QDockWidget's parent during mouseEvents. Here is what I learned from debugging Qt and the solution that I came up with and in the end I did not take anyway: Don't do it, it will cause other unwanted Qt behavior.

What I did was sending MouseMove events before the "re-parenting" and afterwards, to trigger the "dragging" mechanism again (because re-parenting stopped it). This was specific to QDockWidgets, I am not sure if this applies to your situation. However, here is the related code:

```
    // end the drag before re-parenting
    QMouseEvent endDrag(QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseMove, QCursor::pos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    const bool handledEndDrag = QApplication::sendEvent(&dockWidget, &endDrag);
    assert(handledEndDrag);

    // set this attribute to avoid a hide()-event spoiling the drag-and-drop
    dockWidget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_Hidden, true);

    // ... do re-parenting

    dockWidget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_Hidden, false);

    // trigger start drag again
    QMouseEvent* startDrag =
        new QMouseEvent(QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress, dockWidget.mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()),
                        Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, QApplication::keyboardModifiers());
    QApplication::postEvent(&dockWidget, startDrag);

    // fake this mouse move event to continue dragging
    QMouseEvent mouseMove(QEvent::MouseMove, current->pos(), current->pos(), Qt::NoButton,
                QApplication::mouseButtons(), QApplication::keyboardModifiers());
    const bool handledMouseMove = QApplication::sendEvent(m_dock, &mouseMove);
    assert(handledMouseMove);
```

You will have to debug some Qt code in order to understand completely what's going on in your specific case. And as if this was not enough: different Qt versions might behave differently, too.

As you can tell, I had a lot of "fun" doing this. So good luck and may the QForce be with you.

Comment: This seems so awkward when compared to other platforms it's insane... Thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: Well you have to debug the setParent(...) call and see what's going on in there. There might be a solution that can avoid your unwanted effects but that might very specific to your situation. However, you might want to see if there is total different solution for your problem because changing parents during mouse events causes mentioned side-effects.